# How to write app update in iOS?

Tags: ios

have a technic question on writing app updates.

I am redesign my app and adding new features/screens, but not sure whats the best way to manage the code. Right now I am saving old code to separate files in case I need it, and then writing the class from scratch. I am pretty sure there are better ways to do it, like to be able to see old/new version side by side, and would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the best way would be to open a bitbucket.org account, and create a repository for your project there, upload the code you have, and then create a branch for your new code, that way you can compare it at any time.

Comment: Or use a local git repository (Xcode new default setting) or any other kind of [resvision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) software

Comment: local works, hosted in "better" since you now have an off-site backup which complements your local backup plan.